# AlwaysOn Async read takes more time when compared to that of Sync secondary

Tags: sql-server, performance, availability-groups

AlwaysOn Async read takes more time when compared to that of Sync secondary (by a small fraction). Is this expected behaviour? I was under the impression that ASYNC must be faster than the SYNC.

Answer (score 3):

There are a number of different factors involved but it is entirely possible to have a replica that is synchronous be faster or slower than an asynchronous one.

To list a few:

1. Replica is under too much load
2. Hardware specification differences (i.e. synch runs ssd and async runs rotational) or synch is using 8 cores @ 3.6 GHz and async is using 4 cores @ 2.4 GHz
3. Stats and/or indexes were updated and haven't yet been fully redone on the async
4. Geographical network latency

Answer (score 0):

Regarding Asynchronous and Synchronous connections, this is **not about speed of the connection**, but about the results of the synchronization.

1. *Syncronous* - The purpose is to make sure that the Primary server and the synchronously updated Secondary server are kept in synch.  The transaction is only complete once the *Primary and Secondary server transactions are **both committed**.*
2. *Asyncronous* - The purpose is to send the transaction to an asynchronous *'Tertiary'*  server without guaranteeing that both servers have committed the transaction.  This is primarily to deal with slower communication due to bandwidth, network latency (as noted by Sean Gallardy), and so forth.

   Using an Asyncronous connection in this condition prevents the Primary server from being slowed down in its primary work ***while waiting*** for the slower connection to be committed on **both servers**.

So this is about what you are trying to accomplish with each server, not how fast the data is processed.